# How to mention certificate in logstash/eck on kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

By using the operator i install elastic search and kibana its working fine but in the logstash file ssl_certificate_authorities I am confused about How to get and how to mention because by default self-sign certificates are created inside the pod

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should add enviroment logstash pod configuration file and then you can use this certificate in logstash output plugin. You can examine this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77415051/k8s-eck-logstash-pod-connection-issue) and answer.

For the get ssl certificate from elastic secret, you can run below command:

```bash
kubectl get secret yourclustername-es-http-certs-public -o go-template='{{index .data "tls.crt" | base64decode }}'
```

You copy and paste ca.pem file and run below command for fingerprint:

```bash
openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -in ca.pem -noout | sed --expression 's/://g'
```

Output like this:

```bash
sha256 Fingerprint=2650CEEBBEC0D26D9EE9D9DE65T865607A37BFB3C42A5C0301CDC9E5DACCDEF9
```

You can use this fingerprint as value of environment variable in logstash configuration file.